# Trace error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I'm running a bash script on cygwin. The script fails and I'd love to know the state of some enviroment variables in the script. Is there any way to trace the execution of a bash script?

Answer (score 4):

Inside the script you can set flags for verbose, tracing and echoing to examine how the shell is interpreting your statements.

[image: From bash beginner's guide]

```
set -x # expand variables
set +x # turn it off
set -v # set verbose
set +v # turn it off
```

See also: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trap` to call `env` to dump the environment before the script exits.

There are many examples of using `trap` to ensure that temporary files are deleted on exit, which you can easily modify.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script) here.

```
sh -x script [arg1 ...]
bash -x script [arg1 ...]
```

And here is a great post about [HowTo: Debug a Shell Script Under Linux or UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html). I think this would be helpful.